# Deleted an Azure AD tenant I was using for testing, now I can't create a Teams org

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I was testing a new Azure AD tenant that let me play with RBAC, etc in a controlled setting. I was using my defualt Microsoft account, but added the second tenant.

I set up Teams separate from this, and was playing around with that as well. Now that I did my testing, I created a new tenant (under a new domain and account with M365) and set that up. I went ahead and deleted my testing AAD.

Now I am getting errors in logging into Teams, as it says it's looking for a deleted tenant. The error is: AADSTS90002. If I try to sign up for Teams, it says "an error has occurred" (which obviously is not that helpful).

My assumption here is that when I try to log into teams, it is looking for the Teams org on the deleted AAD tenant (which was never my default, incidentally). And when I try to set up a new Teams org through the web, it again tries to go to the deleted tenant.

Is there a way to force my microsoft account to use a different tenant to create this? I've opened a ticket but it's a more delicate issue than most.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but I saw [a doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/teams-desktop-app-can-i-change-logon-account/m-p/28602) it mentioned me that you may try to uninstall the client. Try it?

Comment: Oh that's been tried -- it's an AAD error, not a client issue.

Comment: @Shyatic curious if you ever got this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your issue is more related to Teams product. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.